# Regex for alpha characters unexpectedly matches non-alpha char

Tags: regex

I have been surprised to find that this regex:

```
^([A-z]+)$
```

matches the string:

```
real_estate
```

Through trial and error, I discovered that the following regexes do **not**:

```
^([a-z]+)$
^([A-Za-z]+)$
```

- Why is this so?
- What other non-alpha characters might surprise me in this way?

Note: I'm using the Java regex engine.

Comment: There are non-alpha chars in the range between `Z` and `a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at http://www.ascii-code.com/ `_` is between `A` and `z`

Comment: So any of the following would be matched: `[ \ ] ^ _` and backtick? I always thought `A-z` was just a shorthand for `A-Za-z`.